# Empty Values in HiddenFields with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, geolocation

I'm calling the HTML geolocation method to get latitude and longitude and then storing them into 2 separate HiddenFields. These values from the HiddenFields will then be used in the server side (code behind) which will be stored in a table in my database. I searched high and low over stackoverflow to get help for empty values in HiddenFields, saving latitude and longitude into database, client and server side button click, etc.

I'm actually firing this javascript method based on a button, or do you think it's better to be fired window.onload?

I suspect that the functions aren't fired as well.. I have little knowledge on javascript.. Appreciate any help..

Javascript codes and HiddenFields in my WebForm:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="latitudeTB"/>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="longitudeTB"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideLabel() {
        var seconds = 3;
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("<%=ErrorPanel.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
        }, seconds * 1000);
    };

    //GeoLocation Retrieval
    var latJS = 0;
    var lngJS = 0;
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        //position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
        //var lat = document.getElementById("<%=latitudeTB.ClientID %>");

        latJS = position.coords.latitude;
        lngJS = position.coords.longitude;

        document.getElementById("<%= latitudeTB.ClientID %>").value = latJS;
        document.getElementById("<%= longitudeTB.ClientID %>").value = lngJS;

        alert(document.getElementById("<%= latitudeTB.ClientID %>").value + " " + document.getElementById("<%= longitudeTB.ClientID %>").value);

        /*if (lat) {
            lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
        }*/

        //var long = document.getElementById("<%=longitudeTB.ClientID %>");

        /*if (long) {
            long.value = position.coords.longitude;
        }*/
    }

    function call() {
        getLocation();
        showPosition(position);
    }
</script>
```

FYI. The button is placed above the HiddenFields and Javascript..

Codes for asp:Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BTN_Login" CssClass="btn btn-theme-dark" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClientClick="call();" OnClick="BTN_Login_Click" />
```

I did actually print out the values of the hiddenfields on server side but i'm getting no values at all..

```
    Debug.WriteLine(latitudeTB.Value);
    Debug.WriteLine(longitudeTB.Value);
```

I hope that the code i added is sufficient..

Comment: Can you first check whether you are receiving lattitude and longitude values on client side ?
can you try putting in your showPosition function thses lines of code : console.log(latJS); console.log(latJS);

Comment: sure i'll do that now!

Comment: i received an error unfortunately.. Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this on button click event or on window load event boils down to what you what the user experience to be.

Most websites tend to show the geolocation prompt when the DOM is ready.

You need to tweak your `getLocation` function. `getCurrentPosition` takes success and error callbacks, both of which are not being passed.

```
function getLocation(opts) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( resolve,
                reject,
                opts
            );
        } 
        else {
            reject(new ReferenceError('Browser does not support geolocation api'));
        }

    });
}
```

You can then use it this way:

```
function setLatLong(latId, longId) {
    getLocation()
    .then(function(pos) {
       var coords = pos.coords;
       document.getElementById(latId).value = coords.latitude;
       document.getElementById(longId).value = coords.longitude;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // log or fall back to come other Location API?
    })
}


function call() {
   setLatLong(
     "<%= latitudeTB.ClientID %>",
     "<%= longitudeTB.ClientID %>");
}
```

### Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Hi Oluwafemi, are you using Chrome to run or? I just tried running my website on Microsoft Edge everything works well. Could it be Chrome's issue?

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Sir, i'm not a big fan of copying and pasting codes w/o understanding but can i simply paste every line you've provided into my javascript?

Comment: I checked my Console in Chrome and i got this : Uncaught ReferenceError: call is not defined

Comment: Are you still setting the geolocation on button click?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="BTN_Login" CssClass="btn btn-theme-dark" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClick="BTN_Login_Click" /> currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150907/discussion-between-oluwafemi-sule-and-domster).

Comment: does where i place the hiddenfield and javascript above/below the button affect anything? it's so odd running in Microsoft Edge works but not on Chrome